# How to detect when ReactJS has finished page manipulation?

Tags: reactjs

Our clients add our JS tag to the head of their page. Our tag needs to know when reactJS has finished before it modifies the page.

I have tried using jQuery's `$(document).ready()` but this fires before reactJS has finished. I can use `$(window).load()` but if there are a lot of images on the page, this would be too slow.

What are the options to bind to the completion of `React.renderComponent`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set off the execution of your code via the optional callback that you can pass to [React.renderComponent](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.rendercomponent). This callback won't execute until [React.renderComponent](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.rendercomponent) has finished. If you don't have access to the code that is executing React.renderComponent (which I've just realized is almost definitely the case) then there is no definitive/reliable way to listen for the execution of a function unless of course that function exposes some sort of event that you can listen for, or even guarantees that "x" will be the case once it has finished. Sadly for your case, this doesn't appear to be an option with React.renderComponent.. Let me know if you have any further question.

Comment: thanks pooley. Perhaps our client is willing to use the callback feature of React.renderComponent you mentioned.

Comment: Sure no problem. The more that I think of it, I think that would be an entirely reasonable expectation to place on the client - there's really no avoiding it, and assuming you write the code to be user friendly then it'd be trivial for them to add one line into the call back. It's quite inline with how javascript works with callbacks and general async-ness and whatnot.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't have direct control over the React code, you could always see if you can sniff for relevant changes via [DOM Mutation events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events).

Comment: Would the virtual DOM React creates be of use here?